# Why am I not able to get headers in the intercepted request?

Tags: angular

```
public refreshToken(){
   let options = {

     headers:new HttpHeaders({
       "refresh_token":"djfhhfahsfkhasdfhksdfhhdff",
     })
   }
   this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/refresh_token", options)
   .subscribe((res)=>{
     this.storage.set("access_token", res.body.access_token);
     console.log("token refreshed");
   },(err)=>{
     console.log("error refreshing token");
   });
}
```

In the above code, I have set 'refresh_token' header for the request.
In the httpInterceptor's intercept method I'm logging the request headers before modifying it, but I am not able to see the header "refresh_token" there.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("intercepted");
    console.log(req.headers);
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + "fgdfhgfghjgjghjkghkjghjghjgh",
      })
    });
    console.log(authReq.headers)
    return next.handle(authReq)

  }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try setting headers like this


`if (token) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }`


i think following link would be helpful
https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/07/19/angular-2-new-http-interface-with-interceptors/

Comment: headers set after intercepting the request are working fine. I am not getting headers set before the interception.

Comment: because you are overriding by creating new HttpHeaders object in intercept request.

try below code 
 `const authReq  =    req.clone({ setHeaders: { 
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': "Bearer " + "fgdfhgfghjgjghjkghkjghjghjgh", } });`

Comment: but I'm logging it before overriding it.

Comment: http get function receives 2 argument but you have send 3 in refreshToken function 
change the line 
`this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/refresh_token",{}, options)`
to 
`this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/refresh_token", options)`
hope that works

Comment: still not getting